# Advanced Linq sorting C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sorting

I have an `IQueryable` that has a list of pages.

I want to do: `Pages.OrderByDescending(o => CalculateSort(o.page));`

the method calculate sort is similar to that here is a plain english version:

```
public int calculatesort(page p)
{
    int rating = (from r in db.rating select r). sum();
    int comments = //query database for comments;

    float timedecayfactor = math.exp(-page.totalhoursago);

    return sortscore = (rating +comments)* timedecayfactor;
}
```

when I run a code similar to the one above an error is thrown that the mothode calculatesort cannot be converted to sql.

How can I do a conver the function above to be understood by sql so that I can use it to sort the pages?

Is this not a good approach for large data? Is there another method used to sort sets of results other than dynamically at the database?

I havent slept for days trying to fix this one :(

Comment: Is `Pages` your database entities? I mean `Pages.orderbydescending(o => CalculateSort(o.page))` is linq2object or linq2sql, Also what's your RDBMS and linq provider?

Comment: its Linq to sql. Bassicly there a table called pages and two other tables comments and ratings. I want to use an algorithm similar to that of facebooks Edge rank to rank those algorthims. I could include the rating in comments in a new object when selecting the pages but I still wont be able to translate 
(rating +comments)*math.exp(-page.totalhoursago) into sql. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is nowhere near compiling so I'm guessing a lot here but I hope this gives an idea none the less.
As several have posted you need to give Linq-2-Sql an expression tree. Using query syntax that's what happens (by compiler magic)

```
                     from p in pages
                     let rating = (from r in db.rating
                                   where r.PageId == p.PageId
                                   select r.Value).Sum()
                     let comments = (from c in db.Comments
                                     where c.PageId == p.PageId
                                     select 1).Count()
                     let timedecayfactor = Math.Exp(-(p.totalhoursago))
                     orderby (rating + comments)*timedecayfactor descending
                     select p;
```

I haven't actually tried this against a database, there's simply too many unknown based on your code, so there might still be stuff that can't be translated.

Comment: also I don't think you need select 1, since Linq generates select null if it encounters an aggregate function

Comment: I was meaning that instead of where c.PageId == p.PageId select 1).Count() you can use with no worries c.PageId == p.PageId select c).Count()

Comment: @adrian thx for the point on Math.Exp. A select or group is required. It will not compile without.

Comment: @adrian I don't see how that improves the code though. In the above I find it explicit that I don't care what the value is. Do you see an advantage of selecting the object it self?

Comment: I just made a test, it generates the same T-SQL

Comment: @Rune FS Wow this "Let" is exactly what I was looking for now I able to write incredibly complex sorting querys and calculations. Any idea about the performance of them? How do I test it? If its too heavy what is a solution? is hashing a good option?

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: @MarwanRoushdy the performance heavily depends on your database scheme. You'll have to benchmark it

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because LINQ cannot convert custom code/methods into SQL. It can convert only `Expression<Func<>> objects` into SQL.

In your case, you have a complex logic to do while sorting, so it might make sense to do it using a `Stored Procedure`, if you want to do it in the DB Layer.

Or load all the objects into main memory, and run the calculate sort method on the objects in  memory

**EDIT :**

I don't have the code, so Describing in english is the best I can do :

- Have table with structure capable of temporarily storing all the current users data.
- Have a calculated field in the Pages table that holds the value calculated from all the non-user specific fields
- Write a stored procedure that uses values from these two sources (temp table and calc field) to actually do the sort.
- Delete the temp table as the last part in the stored proc
- You can read about stored procs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/aaa_802/sbrc/sbrc70/sw-sbrc-admin/html/SQLAuthentication-sw-sbrc-admin7.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot load the results into the memory because they are millions of results. Is it possible to convert the code above to Expression<> s? or do I have to use stored procedures. I have zero experience in using sort procedurs

Comment: Or rather an implementer of `IQueryable<T>` will only have limited ability to translate the passed Expression Tree into SQL (or whatever query language). In the Q's case the whole function would need to be translatable...

Comment: Suggested fix: add a calculated column to the DB, and sort on that: this would only need to designate a property in the LINQ expression.

Comment: Id go with Richards suggestion of having a calculated column, and sorting on it. I have always found it okay to trade Hard Disk Space for computation time.

Comment: The actual algorithim is more complicated and also depends on other things such ass userafinity, and interest afinity that are user specific so I cannot store it in the DB. I could reduce the processing by storing the non user specific things in DB I would still need to do the user specific sorting dynamically. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you have current user specific values that are to be used while sorting, and also that you want the sorting to happen in the DB layer, only way I can think of is by using temporary tables. Insert the user specific data into a temporary table structure & then write a Stored Proc that uses the calculated values & temporary table

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to do this? Could you please show me on the simple example I gave in my question? I have no idea on how to do this.

Comment: @Zasz I really need your help!

Comment: @Zasz this method would be too slow on even 10,000 page entries to compare with millions of pages

Answer (score 0):

Linq is expecting Calculatesort to return a "queryable" expression in order to generate its own SQL.

In can embed your 'calculatesort' method in this lambda expression. (I replaced your variables with constants in order to compile in my environment)

```
public static void ComplexSort(IQueryable<string> Pages)
{
    Pages.OrderByDescending(p =>
        {
            int rating = 99;//(from r in db.rating select r). sum();
            int comments = 33;//query database for comments;
            double timedecayfactor = Math.Exp(88);
            return (rating + comments) * timedecayfactor;
        });
}
```

Also, you can even try to run that in parallel (since .net 4.0) replacing the first line with

```
    Pages.AsParallel().OrderByDescending(p =>
```

Comment: if the variables are not constants how could I query the database in the sory dynamically?

Comment: replace the '99' constant with your actual code; and so on for the other constants. Have i answered your question?

Comment: Will this work well with more complex data and about 1 million pages? or is there another aproach? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Marwan: For million records you might want to learn about hash. Also you can do this in a different thread (async) and start it when your system is idle.

Comment: @Luis Filipe: Try it, either it will fail to work, or do sorting via LINQ-to-Objects, which is pointless when you are dealing with Linq2SQL.

Comment: @leppie: I'd say it will order using LINQ-to-Objects. Now i see that it will be very slow to do it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var comments = db.comments.Where(...);
Pages.OrderByDescending(p=>(db.rating.Sum(r=>r.rate) + comments.Count()) * Math.Exp(-p.totalhoursago))
```

Comment: the problem is that rating and comments are not ready available in the page object and would need to be retrieved from the db.

Comment: you'll be going to access the rating and comments via your context reference

Comment: will this be done for every page? The comments and ratings would be different for every page.

Comment: it depends: if there are relations between page and comments and rating then you'll have this p.ratings.Sum() and p.comments.Count(), if not then you have to use like this: db.ratings.Where(r=>r.PageId == p.PageId).Sum() and so on.

Comment: could I use the same method with two dables smth similar to: (from r in db.rating from i in db.interests where r.value == i.value && r.page = page)?? In the example I provided in the question the rating was just a simple example to a much more complex query..

Comment: yes, you can build the query as you want (join, etc) as long its result returns a value like int, decimal, from Sum, Count

Answer (score -1):

Yes, counting previous answers: the LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to translate CalculateSort method. You should convert LINQ to SQL to ordinary LINQ to Object before using custom method.

Try to use this in the way you call the CalculateSort by adding AsEnumerable:

```
Pages.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(o => CalculateSort(o.page));
```

Then you're fine to use the OrderByDescending extension method.

**UPDATE:**
LINQ to SQL will always translate the query in the code into Expression tree. It's quite almost the same concept as AST of any programming language. These expression trees are further translated into SQL expression specific to SQL Server's SQL, because currently LINQ to SQL only supports SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: Strange. Why is my answer downvoted? I just explain my answer as is based on the code in the question.